# pull svn branch to trunk

Tags: svn, merge

Imagine there was a branch created and regularly pulled to the trunk with

```
~/branchdir$ svn merge ^/trunk .
```

no problem, conflicts were resolved on a continuous basis then something happened and no merge was done for months, i.e. branch developed and trunk developed and then, someday later another

```
~/branchdir$ svn merge ^/trunk .
```

was executed and spit out only a single conflict which was followed by a message "resolve all conflicts and rerun the merge to apply the remaining" - is there any way that I can look at all conflicts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The merge is too complex to be done in one step. After the merge stops with the message ‘resolve al conflict ...’ you should resolve the conflicts you have in your local working copy and then commit. Than you can merge again. For very old feature branches the steps could be several.